# Run aspect on proxy object

Tags: spring, proxy, aspectj, spring-aop

I have following simple service:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    @Override
    public void countExternal(Integer arg1) {
        System.out.println("test - lock external");
        count(arg1, new Integer(1));
    }

    public void count(Integer arg1, Integer arg2) {
        System.out.println("test - lock internal");
    }
}
```

that implements my simple interface:

```
public interface TestService {

    void countExternal(Integer arg1);
}
```

Here's the aspect that I am using to do some validation etc. during **count** method:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TestAdvicer {

    @Around("execution(* count(..))")
    public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // do som magic here
        return joinPoint.proceed();

    }
}
```

In my Spring configuration I have included autoproxying:
`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`

Unfortunately, my `TestAdvicer` is never executed since `count` method is invoked from `countExternal` method. `count` method is executed on Proxy object and because of that advice didn't run.

Do you know how can I run my advice on Proxy object? What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't through Spring's AOP functionality. You'll need a full AOP language (AspectJ) to do it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ist right. He should have written an answer for it so as to close the question. Let me add a link to the Spring AOP manual, chapter [Understanding AOP proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). Therein, search for the term "self-invocation" in order to get a really good explanation as to _why_ it does not work with Spring AOP, but with AspectJ.